# Filter data frame with several columns to unique id

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a huge data frame like this (with several ids repeated in different rows):

```
Id  Phone   Email   Product Age
1   Null    g@      A       20
1   028     g@      Null    Null
1   028     Null    A       Null
2   040     Null    B       25 
2   Null    t@      B       Null
3   015     b@      E       23
4   023     c@      D       30
```

How can I get a final data frame with an expected output like:

```
Id  Phone   Email   Product Age
1   028     g@      A       20
2   040     t@      B       25 
3   015     b@      E       23
4   023     c@      D       30
```

In the final output I expected unique ids with all the information aggregate in a single row. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jezrael I'm not sure that's what Thabra means/needs. IIUC it looks like s/he wants to 'squash' together the valid data for each column per id.

Comment: Yes, I changed the example. 
I need a final data frame with all info about an unique id in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your real DF has `NaN`'s instead of `Null`'s:

```
In [165]: df.groupby('Id').first()
Out[165]:
    Phone Email Product   Age
Id
1    28.0    g@       A  20.0
2    40.0    t@       B  25.0
3    15.0    b@       E  23.0
4    23.0    c@       D  30.0
```

otherwise:

```
In [168]: df.replace('Null', np.nan).groupby('Id').first()
Out[168]:
   Phone Email Product Age
Id
1    028    g@       A  20
2    040    t@       B  25
3    015    b@       E  23
4    023    c@       D  30
```

or alternatively (if you hit a [bug, specified by @jezrael in comments](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427)):

```
In [171]: df.replace('Null',np.nan).groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()]).reset_index()
Out[171]:
   Id Phone Email Product Age
0   1   028    g@       A  20
1   2   040    t@       B  25
2   3   015    b@       E  23
3   4   023    c@       D  30
```

Comment: Perhaps there is need for replacing Null with np.nan

Comment: Better dont use it, because [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427)

Comment: @jezrael, added an alternative solution

Comment: `.head(1)` would also work too. I liked the `first_valid_index`. You have my vote : ). And would `df.replace('Null',np.nan).groupby('Id').agg('first')` lead to any bugs?

Comment: @Dark, IMO `.agg('first')` should produce the same result as `.first()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use if want only first values:

```
f = lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0]
df = df.replace('Null', np.nan).groupby('Id').agg(f)
print (df)
   Phone Email Product Age
Id                        
1    028    g@       A  20
2    040    t@       B  25
3    015    b@       E  23
4    023    c@       D  30
```

But if want all unique values:

```
f = lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().drop_duplicates().astype(str))
#alternative solution
#f = lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.dropna()))
df = df.replace('Null', np.nan).groupby('Id').agg(f)
print (df)
   Phone Email Product Age
Id                        
1    028    g@       A  20
2    040    t@       B  25
3    015    b@       E  23
4    023    c@       D  30
```